# load data from cassandra to flink

Tags: api, cassandra, apache-flink

How can i read from cassandra using flink in java or python.I didn't find a good documentation on this subject.And i want to connect this code to my website.How is that.

I have this code but it runs out an exception

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/api/common/typeinfo/TypeHint
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeHint
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

```
import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeHint;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple5;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.typeutils.TupleTypeInfo;
import org.apache.flink.batch.connectors.cassandra.CassandraInputFormat;
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.cassandra.ClusterBuilder;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        ClusterBuilder clusterBuilder = new ClusterBuilder() {

            @Override
            public Cluster buildCluster(Cluster.Builder builder) {

                return builder.addContactPoint("127.0.0.1").withPort(9042).build();
            }
        };

        DataSet<Tuple5<String,String,String,Integer,String>> inputRecords = env
                .createInput
                        (new CassandraInputFormat<Tuple5<String,String,String,Integer,String>>("Select profilealternative from profiles.profile LIMIT 1 ;",clusterBuilder)
            ,TupleTypeInfo.of(new TypeHint<Tuple5<String,String,String,Integer,String>>() {}));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class you are missing in classpath comes from flink-dist.jar file ( name also depends on version for e.g, flink-dist_2.12-1.9.0.jar). Please check the file is in your classpath while running the program. Also you might require other jars typically present in apache-flink distribution `lib` directory. You may also create a fat jar containing all the dependencies and then run.

Answer (score 0):

The main cause for your problem is `ClassNotFoundException` - this means that your application doesn't link all required libraries to create an uberjar, or the corresponding libraries are missing from classpath.